# why distance(iterator,vector.begin()) returns a random number?

Tags: c++, iterator

I am writing codes as follows.  No matter how I call 'next' method, distance between iterator `it` and `vector.begin()` returns a random number, never returns the number of `next` method I call. Could someone explain this to me?  And there is runtime error I shown at the bottom.

```
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
class Vector2D {
       ::vector<::vector<int>> vector;
       std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator it;
       std::vector<int>::iterator inner;
   
public:
    Vector2D(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vec):vector(vec),it(begin(vec)),inner(it->begin()){
    }
    int next() {
            if(it != (vector.end()-1)&& inner != it->end()-1)
            {   inner++;
                std::cout<<"it position:"<<distance(it,vector.begin())<<endl;
                return *inner;
            }
            else if (it != (vector.end()-1)&& inner == it->end()-1)
            {   advance(it,1);
                std::cout<< "it position:"<<std::distance(it,vector.begin())<<endl;
                if(it != vector.begin()+1){
                    std::cout<<"weird"<<endl;
                }
                inner=it->begin();
                return *inner;
                    
            }
            else if (it == (vector.end()-1)&& inner != it->end()-1)
            {
                
                inner++;
                return *inner;
            }
            else
            {          
                        return -1;
            }
         
            }
            
};
```

The error is as follows:

```
Line 815: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_iterator.h)
0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:820:16
```

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> it(begin(vec))
> ```

`it` points to `vec`.

> ```
> it != (vector.end()-1)
> ```

You compare `it` with an iterator to `vector`. `vector` is not the same container as `vec`. Iterators that you compare are not to the same container, and hence the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: I changed the constructor line```Vector2D(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vec):vector(vector),it(begin(vec)),inner(it->begin()){     }.``` Random number problems are gone, but there is still run time error commented on constructor line: ```member call on null pointer of type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>' (solution.cpp)```. Could you help me with it? Thanks!